# Disabling sonarqube rules on comments

Tags: sonarqube

In my current project we have used a lot of comments explaining what the code does and so on. While running sonar for this these comments are causing lot of issues, I wanted to know if there is a way to disable comments check in sonarqube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have administrator permissions, you can turn any rule on or off (or sometimes reconfigure it) in the quality profile.  Navigate to your quality profile, find the rule you want to disable, and turn it off.

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Rules for full details.

Comment: Ok.. so if I disable comments checking will this be eligible for comments that are along with a line of java code say after the ';'

Comment: Look and see what's available. My SonarQube installation (4.0) has 10 rules that come up when I search for a key of "comment". Some are enabled by default, others are not. Several are configured by a regular expression, which you can change.

Comment: The link mentioned has expired! Probably you would like to point to the following link? https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Rules

Comment: @InduDevanath That link also expired. Is this one appropriate? https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/rules/

Comment: Probably, the link keeps changing. Better to trust google in this case :)